Stylesheet issue in treewidget in pyqt5?
Code below populate a treewidget. TO change the design of the rows in treewidget, we add CSS like codes to stylesheet of the treewidget like below:
        self.treeWidget = QTreeWidget()

        stylesheet = ("""QTreeView::item {padding: 2px; 
                      border-bottom: 1px solid black;
                      }
                      QTreeView::item:selected {
                        background-color: black;                      
                        }""")

        self.treeWidget.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)

I just discovered if we set Gray in here, nothing happens when a row is selected:
QTreeView::item:selected {
                        background-color: Gray;                      
                        }

But if we change the colour to Blue or any other colours, the style of the selected row becomes unusual! There will be dotted borders all over the cells where we select in that selected row!
Why this issue does not happen with Gray? How we can set other colours without facing problems?
Please have a look at the selected Blue row. The cell has a dotted border!
The Gray row is clean without dotted border


I would like to change the colour of the selected row without those dotted border.

It certainly has the border in both cases, the difference is that since the background color is also the same of the focus border, you don't see it.

@musicamante in fact, there is nothing selectable in Gray. While all the cells are selectable and therefore, have borders with other colours. Gray gives a solid row. Why is it like this I have no idea!>

I've already explained it. The gray dotted line isn't a border, is a focus rectangle (which doesn't necessarily include selection); when using a contrasting color (if the selection is active) it becomes gray, as that's the default against the selection palette color, but since you're overriding a gray background, you just don't see it. If you just want to avoid that, see 1 and 2. If you want more customization, clarify your exact needs, but remember that with complex widgets if one property is set all others must be as well.

@musicamante Thank you! You gave me some useful clues about this issue. Now it is fixed!

To solve this issue, the method is to disable focus indication.
outline: none; /* Remove focus outline for all items */

One way is to modify the stylesheet in this way:
        self.treeWidget = QTreeWidget()

    stylesheet = ("""QTreeView::item {padding: 2px; 
                  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
                  outline: none; /* Remove focus outline for all items */
                  }
                  QTreeView::item:selected {
                    background-color: black;                      
                    }""")

    self.treeWidget.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)

Annother way is:
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt     
self.treeWidget.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)  # Disable focus


Disabling focus capabilities on the view is a terrible work around. Your issue is about displaying, while disabling focus prevents interaction. Since the problem is with appearance, use the solution that actually deals with that. Anything else that would affect other and unrelated behavior is a wrong choice.

@musicamante Thank you. I disabled the focus on treeView and it did not make any differences in the performance of the application. Maybe I am a newbie in this, but I cannot see the benefits of it, or the drawbacks of disabling it at all. The application does its jobs as before. Could you tell me how it could make any issues somewhere, please?
